# Using Polymorphism in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, mvp

In a module of a win forms application I have a hierarchy of classes like `BaseRecovery`, `LoanRecovery` and `FineRecovery`. Both `LoanRecovery` and `FineRecovery` inherits from `BaseRecovery`. All these models have one view called `RecoveryForm` where you can enter/view loans and fines of employees. and I'm planing to use one Presenter class called `RecoveryPresenter` which inherits from `BasePresenter`.

LoanRecovery class will be as follows...

```
Class LoanRecovery : BaseRecovery
{
    public string LoanID {get;set;}
    public DateTime IssueDate {get;set;}
    public Decimal Amount {get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So I'd do the following in Programe.cs.

```
IBaseRcovery recovery=null;
IRecoveryForm recoveryForm = new RecoveryForm();
IDataService dataService = new DataService();

BasePresenter presenter = new RecoveryPresenter( recovery, recoveryForm, dataService );
presenter.Show(); // This will display the form recoveryForm
```

In the presenter I would say

```
public RecoveryPresenter( IBaseRecover model, IRecoveryForm view, IDataService dataService )
{
    this._Model = model;
    this._View = view;
    this._DataService = dataService;            
    WireUpViewEvents();

}
```

Now lets say if I need to give a loan, I would run `SetModelPropertisFromView()` mehtod in the `BasePresenter` class which use reflection. But before that I should pass an instance of `LoanRecovery` class (i.e. a Model).

I know that the run time polimorphism could be used in this case but I have no idea how to to that! Please could you let me know a way to to this?

Is it ok if I do in Presenter like this?

```
    public void Issue()
    {
        if (_View.Type == "Loan")
        {
            _Model = new LoanRecovery();
        }

        if (_View.Type == "Fine")
        {
            ...
        }

        if (_View.Type == "Insurance")
        {
            ...
        }

        SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View, _DataService); //Update model properties from the view
        dataService.InsertLoan(_Model);
    }
```

Comment: That would work. Your `SetModelPropertiesFromView` would have to use similar logic to make sure it updates the correct properties based on `_View.Type`. But this leads to other issues because `SetModelPropertiesFromView`, I'm guessing, will be used by other views, therefore you cannot use `_View.Type` in that method because it may make sense in relation to this view, but not when used by others. In this case your "update using reflection" strategy would have to move from the base class into the presenter class containing the `Issue` method.

Comment: @ MotoSV, As you said earlier this would work if I create localModelInstance. But the problem is that will breach the concept of using constructor injection. Here I've injected BaseRecovery instance to the presenter. but instead of using that, presenter new a child object (either FineRecovery or LoanRecovery)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are already using polymorphism through the `IRecovery` interface. Basically polymorphism is a way of interacting with different types of objects through a common interface. This can be through an actual interface definition, for example `IRecovery`, or a base class such as `BaseRecovery`. You can read more here:

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

From looking at your code samples I would make one or two changes. First make your `BaseRecovery` class abstract so that I instance cannot be created. This will force you to use either `LoanRecovery` or `FineRecovery` which are more meaningful, concrete, implementations of `IRecovery`. In your programe.cs replace the `new BaseRecovery` with either `new LoanRecovery` or `new FineRecovery` based on what you want to display in your view.

When it comes to updating the model with values from your presenter all you have to do is run your reflection code. The `SetModelPropertiesFromView` method should take a `IRecovery` and in there you call `GetType()` which will return type information for whatever type of object `IRecovery` is pointing at. From this type information you can then enumerate the properties and update each property with the values from your view.

EDIT 1:
It just occurred to me that you run into a problem with this. The reason being you are using the same view for updating two different models so how does the view know which model it is updating and therefore which properties need to be set. The only thing I can think of is your `SetModelPropertiesFromView` looks at the type information and if it's one type then update some properties, but if it's another type then update other properties.

Comment: Actually at the entry point(progamme.cs) we dont know which type of object need to be created. It depends on the selection of the type in the form. So that If I do some thing like this, is it ok? (Ive edited the question too) public void Issue()
        {
            if (_View.Type == "Loan")
            {
                _Model = new LoanRecovery();
            }
            if (_View.Type == "Fine")
            {                
            }

            if (_View.Type == "Insurance")
            {
            }
            SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View, _DataService);
        }

Comment: Does your view bind to properties on your presenter or the model? If it binds to your presenter, then you may not have to create your model up front. Instead  in the `GiveLoan` method create an instance of your model (let's call it localModelInstance) using the "if type" logic, call `SetModelPropertiesFromView` passing in the model instance and the finally call `DataService.InsertLoan(localModelInstance)`.

Comment: I just updated the Qus :) No its not bound to presenter. its bound to the model. Please see my new code in presenter.It dynamically creates instances based on the logic. Is that considered run time polymorphism?